# MYSQL Table Alignment Formatting

Tags: mysql

Im currently working on an assignment in MYSQL where my scenario is to create a database for the army (i picked the scenario, dont ask why). My problem however, is that after creating the table and populating it, the format of the table is displayed of when i do a `SELECT` command. Somthing like this:

```
+---------------------------------------------+----------+----------------+----------------+------------+
| Name                                        | Codename | Type           | FOB            | Combatants |
+---------------------------------------------+----------+----------------+----------------+------------+
| 12 Régiment blindé du Canada              | Adsum    | Armour         | CFB Valcartier |          9 |
| 5 Régiment d'artillerie légère du Canada | Ubique   | Artillery      | CFB Valcartier |         12 |
| 5 Combat Engineer Regiment                  |          | Support        | CFB Valcartier |          5 |
| 3rd Battalion, Royal 22e Régiment          | Vipère  | Light Infantry | CFB Valcartier |          5 |
| The Canadian Grenadier Guards               | Vipère  | Light Infantry | Montreal       |          5 |
+---------------------------------------------+----------+----------------+----------------+------------+
```

I cant figure out why this is happening, the number of characters in each field is less then what is set when i created the table so this should not happen. Heres my table desc:

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Name       | varchar(50) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Codename   | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Type       | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| FOB        | varchar(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| Combatants | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

All my other tables come out correctly aligned, so i dont know why this table is like this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The output you're getting in the command-line interface is quite irrelevant. The data is stored appropriately, and the output is merely an example of how your data is stored in the table

> I can hear in my mind a Granpa Simpson saying:
>   *"Back in my days [the 80's], when you told a database program to output columns with a fixed width, the database program just did that and nothing else!"*

(Well, douh! *I* was born in the 80's :S )

If you need to force a format, you should write a front-end program (using Python, Java, Perl, or whatever language you want), which connects itself to your database, retreives the data, formats it, and prints it on the screen.

Alternatively, you can use [MySQL built-in string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) to format your data according to your designs; for example:

> [`RPAD(str,len,padstr)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_rpad): Returns the string `str`, right-padded with the string `padstr` to a length of `len` characters. If `str` is longer than `len`, the return value is shortened to `len` characters